# No longer able to execute python code in Vscode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Suddenly vsCode on Mac Mojave stopped running any python code.
running a simple *print(1)* produces the following error:

> cd /Users/sammy/Code/python/Socratica ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8"
>   "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" python
>   /Users/sammy/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.12.1/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py
>   --default --client --host localhost --port 49677 /Users/sammy/Code/python/Socratica/lambda1.py 1
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/sammy/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.12.1/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py",
>   line 45, in 
>       main(ptvsdArgs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/sammy/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.12.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/**main**.py",
>   line 265, in main
>       wait=args.wait)
>
> File
>   "/Users/sammy/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.12.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/**main**.py",
>   line 258, in handle_args
>       debug_main(addr, name, kind, *extra, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/sammy/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.12.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/_local.py",
>   line 45, in debug_main
>       run_file(address, name, *extra, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/sammy/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.12.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/_local.py",
>   line 79, in run_file
>       run(argv, addr, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/sammy/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.12.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/_local.py",
>   line 140, in _run
>       _pydevd.main()
>
> File
>   "/Users/sammy/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.12.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py",
>   line 1936, in main
>       if setup['cmd-line']: TypeError: '**NoneType' object is not callable**

I am using the first option this launch.json file

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5678,
            "host": "localhost"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "enter-your-module-name-here",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "django": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (External Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

I removed the python extension and reinstalled it but that didn't help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode somehow lost the python.pythonPath. Everything worked after setting to to usr/local/bin/python3 or selecting the correct environment from VSCode status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Its a temporary Work around but it worked for me, i commented the lines

```
if setup['cmd-line']:
        debugger.wait_for_commands(globals)
```

[image]

also should try [github discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3370)